# Disk management unable to connect to virtual disk service

Tags: windows-10, disk-management

On Win 10 in Computer Management (local), I click on Disk Management and see "Unable to connect to Virtual Disk Service".

The obvious thing to check was whether VDS was running. It was not, and was set to start manually. I changed it to automatic start, and started it. When I tried Disk Management again, I got the same message. Back in Services, Virtual Disk is no longer running. Actually, Services says it's running but there's also the option to start the service; see [Virtual Disk running and startable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdZuS.png). But if I open a new Services window, it's not running. Clicking Start at this point doesn't get me anywhere.

I've searched at length, tried sfc and dism, without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Manual start is correct but I don't see an issue with it being set to auto. Diskpart.exe will also use VDS in the same way as the MMC snap in for Disk management,  I assume if you run from an admin prompt: `dispart.exe` this errors or hangs? Do you have any removable storage devices attached?  Same problem if they are removed? What other software, maybe security related do you have installed?

Comment: Did you check the event viewer yet?

Comment: @helpinghand: diskpart starts and quits, no message. No removable storage devices. I have Eset installed.

Comment: @albin: error is: VDS fails to launch provider {CA7DE14F-5BC8-48FD-93DE-A19527B0459E}. Error code: 80072498@0200000C. Source is VDS, Event ID is 15, level is Error.

Comment: Then that's possibly your problem. Did you try to research the error yet?

Comment: @Albin: yes, I checked. Nothing that helped.

Comment: A little more detailed info would be helpfull, what exactly did you find / try to fix and how?

Comment: @Albin: a search for 80072498@0200000C didn't give very much. What I found involved HYPER-V (which I don't use) and updating server drivers for old versions of Windows.

Comment: then you have to use and/or include the other parts of the error message as well to widen your search results. I immediately found several suggestions and solutions: e.g. this page [this page](http://wiki-170739.usedtech.org/vds-fails-to-launch-provider-error-code.html)??

Comment: @Albin: what search criteria did you use? I tried including the event ID and that didn't help. The page you cited only links to a proprietary tool, which I have no basis for trusting.

Comment: @Albin: DId you see my comment on the answer below? Clean boot got disk management back and I'm selectively reenabling process & startup items.

Comment: Interesting, did you find out what actually caused the problem?

Comment: @Albin: Not yet. I didn't have to do with any of the services; it worked after all were re-enabled. I've been adding back startup programs one by one but haven't come to it yet. If I manage to identify a specific program, I'll make note here.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you are running any third-party anti-virus application, if yes, please uninstall the anti-virus application.

For test purposes, please try to clean-boot the system, and check if the issue still exists in clean boot.

Please check if there's any disk error in the event log, if yes, please try to un-attach the non-system drive, check if it could work.

If the above method not works, we may need to collect some information to analyze the issue.

As Disk Management snap-in works closely with Virtual Disk Service, We may enable VDS registry key on the problematic server to capture the VDS log file for the analysis.

a.         Click Start, click Run, type Regedit, and then click OK.

b.         Locate the following subkey:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\vds

c.          Right-click the vds subkey, point to New, and then click Key.

d.         Name the new key DebugLog.

e.          Right-click the new DebugLog key, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.

f.           Name the new value Level.

Double-click the new Level value, Set the value to 15 (hex 0xF) to on the Value data text box, and then click OK.

g.         The $VDS$.log file is created in the %Systemroot%\System32 folder.

Meanwhile, please also try using Process monitor to capture the process when you can reproduce the issue.

Steps:

1. Download process monitor from the link given here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

2. Run the process monitor on the problematic server
3. Start Process Monitor. You will see File/Registry activity is being captured.

Press Ctrl+E to stop logging data.

Press Ctrl+X to clear the currently captured data.

Under Process Monitor, press Ctrl+E to start gathering data.

4. Now try to reproduce the issue.

Try to Open Disk Management console to reproduce the issue with the error message "Unable to Connect to Virtual Disk Service"

5. Under Process Monitor, Press Ctrl+E to stop capturing.
6. Please save the captured data from Process Monitor to a file (File->Save)
7. Press Ctrl + L to launch the Process Monitor filter.

Comment: Clean boot did the trick. So now I'll go and selectively re-enable stuff.

Comment: Then, it seems some third party application block the VDS starting.